# Is there a way to deactivate the debugging output of Akka?

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor, akka

While working with Akka, I have implemented a simple command line app.

But Akka also prints statements to the command line like:

```
[GENERIC] [27.10.11 22:57] [RemoteClientStarted(akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteSupport@b07f45d,/127.0.0.1:3000)]
[GENERIC] [27.10.11 22:57] [RemoteClientConnected(akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteSupport@b07f45d,/127.0.0.1:3000)]
[GENERIC] [27.10.11 22:57] [RemoteClientShutdown(akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteSupport@b07f45d,/127.0.0.1:3000)]
[GENERIC] [27.10.11 22:57] [RemoteClientDisconnected(akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteSupport@b07f45d,/127.0.0.1:3000)]
```

Is there a way to disable this debugging output (or redirect it to somewhere else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a few things to hide the [GENERIC] log tags. Not sure if all of this is needed, but it seems to work.

Added the following to my `akka.conf`

```
 event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
 event-handler-level = "WARNING"
```

Make sure you are changing the right akka.conf, you may have an AKKA_HOME specified or you may have dropped an akka.conf onto your classpath by mistake.

Also made the following changes at the bottom of my `logback.xml`

```
<logger name="akka" level="WARNING"/>
<root level="WARNING">
<!--    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/> -->
<appender-ref ref="R"/>
</root>
```

Your `logback.xml` should live right next to your `akka.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the docs can be of assistance:

[EventHandler](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/general/event-handler.html)

Comment: Where would I have to place such a configuration file?

Comment: Perhaps the docs can be of assistance: http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/general/configuration.html